# How to show data with picture from database?

Tags: database, excel, vba

From this how to: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database

if I add picture in each data (hyperlink or comment), can I show that data with picture??

Comment: use a hyperlink pointing to the picture in a foder? I mean is excel, that should be a solution for using excel as database

Comment: I mean add picture to excel in each data in data sheet
and I want it to show picture too in View sheet when filter data

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have no direct way to work with Pics using SQL in Excel.

But there is an option to paste Pics from folder.

### **Step 1.**

Make request using SQL and get Full Path to each picture in your table, for example:

> 'C:\Users\Usermname\Pictures\1.png'

=>

### **Step 2.**

Use VBA-code to paste Pictures into Table:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim i
Call KillAllPics("Sheets1")
For i = 1 To 7
    Call InsertPics(Range("B1").Offset(i - 1, 0), _
    Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, 100)
Next i
End Sub

Sub KillAllPics(SheetName As String)
Dim Shape As Shape
For Each Shape In Sheets(SheetName).Shapes
   If Shape.Type = 13 Then Shape.Delete
Next Shape
End Sub

Sub InsertPics(rng As Range, link As String, heigth As Integer)
' rng -- where to paste image
' link -- text link with image
' heigth -- change heigth of cell with picture
If Dir(link) <> "" Then
    rng.RowHeight = heigth
    Dim L, T, W, H

    Dim objImage
    With rng
        T = .Top + 2
        H = .Height * 0.95
        L = .Left + 2
    End With

    Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

    objImage.LoadFile link
        W = objImage.Width * (H / objImage.Height)
        If W > rng.Width Then
        W = rng.Width * 0.95
        H = objImage.Height * (W / objImage.Width)
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture link, False, True, L, T, W, H
End If
End Sub
```

This code first delete old Pictures from WorkSheet, then it pastes pictures into cells. It also fits each picture and resize it to Size of Cell.

Comment: great, but can I integrate this function to the system like a link  http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database  ??
sorry but I'm very rookie.